# django how to do something if value of form submitted is a certain word

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-errors

Okay so I have django model and created a form of that model. Here is my template:

```
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.first_name }} {{form.last_name }} <br>
    {{ form.username }} {{ form.password }} <br>
    {{ form.date_of_birth_month }} {{ form.date_of_birth_day }} {{ form.date_of_birth_year }}
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>


{% for field, error in form.errors.items %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
        {{ error | striptags }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now, here is my model of that form.

```
class Users(models.Model): 
    months = (
        ('Month','Month'), ('January', 'January'), ('February','February'), ('March','March'), ('April','April'), ('May','May'), ('June','June'), ('July','July'), ('August','August'), ('September','September'), ('October','October'), ('November','November'), ('December','December'),
)
    days = (
        ('Day', 'Day'), ('1','1'), ('2','2'), ('3','3'), ('4','4'), ('5','5'),)
    years = (
        ('Year','Year'), ('2013','2013'), ('2012','2012'), ('2011','2011'), ('2010','2010'), ('2009','2009'), ('2008','2008'),)

    user_id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    username = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.SlugField(max_length=50)

    date_of_birth_month = models.CharField(verbose_name='', max_length=9, choices=months, default='Month')
    date_of_birth_day = models.CharField(verbose_name='', max_length=3, choices=days, default='Day')
    date_of_birth_year = models.CharField(verbose_name='', max_length=4, choices=years, default='Year')
```

Now, the default for the month choices box is 'Month' and the user name click the drop down and pick which month he was born in. Same for Day and Year. However, this makes Month, Day and Year an option which the user can pick. How can I make it so that if the user selects 'Month' as the month, 'Day' as the day or 'Year' as the year, then raise an error message saying 'Please select a valid Month / Day / Year'?

my view is here:

```
def home_page(request):
    form = UsersForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UsersForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    c.update({'form':form})
    return render_to_response('home_page.html', c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the clean method for fields in your form:

```
class UsersForm(form.Form):
    # form fields here

    def clean_month(self):
        month = self.cleaned_data.get('month')
        if month:
            try:
                month = int(month)
            except:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid month')
            if month < 1 or month > 12:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid month')

        return month
```

Do this for rest of fields which you want to validate. More help is in [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/)

Comment: Yes i was assuming the month has to be an integer, you can skip that check then. BTW why don't you just give a single date field and store in db. And on front end use datepicker for ease that will save a lot of work for you.

Comment: Ah, okay perfect. Also, you said "if month: try: month = int(month)".. wouldn't the value for month always be a string since I am only giving them options of January-December? What I was thinking was, def clean_date_of_brith_month(self): data = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth_month') if month == 'Month': raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid month').. but it didn't work.. any ideas why?

Comment: try to print the value of `self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth_month')` before doing anything and check if value is really `Month` or something else is coming which is failing `if month == 'Month':` condition

Comment: Hm because I wanted the month field to be it's own button which certain choices, the day field to be it's own button with certain choices and the year field to be it's own button which certain choices. Is there a way to do that and store it as just a single date field in the database? Also, is there a good documentation on how to use datepicker?

Comment: hm.. when I do print(data) in the view, it doesn't do anything.. should I just add {{ data }} in the template? I am using Vim.

Comment: There is [DateField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datefield) for forms. You need to look more here.